# React Native How to Loop render image and skip null object from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

React Native How to Loop render image and skip null object from API

I have my api like this
:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "localityno": "01",
            "ocationname": "Sushi xA",
            "image1": "www.abc.com/abc1.jpg",
            "image2": "www.abc.com/abc2.jpg",
            "image3": "www.abc.com/abc3.jpg",
            "image4": "www.abc.com/abc4.jpg",
            "image5": "www.abc.com/abc5.jpg",
        },
        {
            "localityno": "02",
            "ocationname": "Park Zoo",
            "image1": "www.abc.com/w1.jpg",
            "image2": "www.abc.com/w2.jpg",
            "image3": "",                 <<<<<<< it's null *****
            "image4": "www.abc.com/w4.jpg",
            "image5": "",                 <<<<<<< it's null *****
        },
    ]

}
```

### ----------------------------------------------

And this is my static render code :
it's return blank image if image url it's null

**I want to looping and skip null object**

Thank You.

```
    componentWillMount() {

      return fetch("www.myservice.com/endpoint")
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,

             dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.result),
           }, function() {

           });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           alert("0 : Recrods On This Module ")
         });

    }

    render() {

      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 7,overflow: 'hidden'}}>

        <ListView
          enableEmptySections={true}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={
            (rowData) =>

                  <Image source={{uri: rowData.image1}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
                  <Image source={{uri: rowData.image2}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
                  <Image source={{uri: rowData.image3}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
                  <Image source={{uri: rowData.image4}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
                  <Image source={{uri: rowData.image5}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />

          }
        />

        </View>

      );
    }
}

export default Feed;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a function that dynamically build the items and skip the empty images. Something like this:

```
(rowData) => {
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        const key = 'image' + i;
        const uri = rowData[key];
        if (!uri) continue;
        items.push(<Image key={key} source={{uri: uri}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />);      
    }
    return <View>{items}</View>
}
```

Comment: I'm a newbie on js i don't know how to fix it i got a error  on real env webservice for production "staticRenderer.render a valid react element"
can you guide me thank you

=  https://gist.github.com/boyinfotronics/35575d612333c9add0ffa1b66fb118f0

Comment: Don't forget that every row in `ListView` should be one element. It means that you can't return array from renderRow function. Instead you should wrap it into something. For example

```
<View>
  {items}
</View>
```

Also don't forget required attribute `key`.

Comment: @KonstantinYakushin, that's correct, I've added the changes you've suggested.

Comment: Thank You Everyone.